# How can I convert these Fortran statements to C#?

Tags: c#, fortran

I have been tasked with converting several Fortran files over to C#. I do not have a choice and in this situation cannot use a Dot net driver to read Fortran. I am an amateur when it comes to C# and used Fortran in 1983 as my one and only time.

I have a couple of clauses which I can't seem to figure out how to relate in C# - would someone point me in the right direction, please?

I have a lot of instances in Fortran where an array is Allocated using an ALLOCATABLE command. I do not know how to do similar in C#, later on, in code, I need to reference this allocation as a check as well.

I have a Type declaration:

```
TYPE Cell
  DOUBLE PRECISION, POINTER :: column(:)
END TYPE Cell
```

How do I convert this Declaration to C#?

I have assignments using the above declaration:

```
TYPE(Cell), POINTER           :: PMAT(:)
TYPE(Cell), POINTER           :: PMATD(:) 
TYPE(Cell), POINTER           :: NMATD(:)
```

How do I declare these variables in C#?

Comment: Do a little research on Arrays in c# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/ You will find it a lot more robust than in Fortran...I would even back up a little further and get up to speed with object oriented programming...as you could have arrays of objects.

Comment: I can get the array portion, I am confused on the Type declaration and how to get it assigned to a pointer within the array. All this was probably explained badly.

Comment: Without the context, why there are pointers to pointers used, it is quite difficult to answer this question.

Comment: The [new operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-operator) is used for allocation in C#. Somethings can't be directly converted - similarly it is a long time since I used Fortran (maybe 1982) - but the type declaration appears to have an array of pointers to doubles - the equivalent of pointers in C# are references, but other than as parameters you cannot declare references to value types (eg doubles), so there may not be a direct conversion. Also you would need to be aware that by default Fortran arrays start at index 1, C# arrays start at 0.

Comment: Yes, I have been taking into account that C# arrays start at zero.  The program is used to evaluate weighted operational models.  These models can contain hundreds of variables from various industrial instruments.  

I am aware there might not be a direct conversion, I probably will need to code something to convert this.  The client wasn't comfortable supporting Fortran and wanted it converted to C#.  And hence where I am now.

Comment: I don't envy you the task, best of luck

Comment: Feedback: I have not voted, but the title of "looking for help" (now edited out) is likely to make readers' hearts sink. As a summary, it says "here is a really broad question and I'd like someone to do the lion's share of the work". If you can make your question titles more specific, that may get your questions a better reception. (Of course, you may have researched this thoroughly, and may be looking only for a small piece of assistance, but perception matters).

Comment: Thank you, Paul, as well as Chris.  The Microsoft guide helps but I still need to figure out how to get the referencing configured.  I am targeting to get the code running this week.  I still need to determine how to code in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a C# programmer either, but to get some experience, I've tried to create minimum examples by looking at tutorial pages. The first code is a jagged array that @HPM mentions in his answer:

```
using static System.Console;

class Program {

    static void Main() {

        double[][] pmat;            // reference to a jagged array
        pmat = new double[ 2 ][ ];  // creates a jagged array of size 2

        pmat[ 0 ] = new double[ 3 ];
        pmat[ 1 ] = new double[ 4 ];

        pmat[ 0 ][ 1 ] = 777.0;
        pmat[ 1 ][ 2 ] = 888.0;

        foreach( var x in pmat[ 0 ] ) WriteLine( x );  // prints 0 777 0
        foreach( var x in pmat[ 1 ] ) WriteLine( x );  // prints 0 0 888 0
    }
}
```

The 2nd code is the use of `struct`, which is a value type and probably similar to `type` in Fortran. So the literal translation of  OP's code might look like

```
using static System.Console;

public struct Cell
{
    public double[] column;    // reference to a double array
}

class Program {

    static void Main() {

        Cell[] pmat;  // reference to a Cell array

        pmat = new Cell[ 2 ];  // allocates an array of Cell objects

        pmat[ 0 ].column = new double[ 3 ];
        pmat[ 1 ].column = new double[ 4 ];

        pmat[ 0 ].column[ 1 ] = 777.0;
        pmat[ 1 ].column[ 2 ] = 888.0;

        foreach( var x in pmat[ 0 ].column ) WriteLine( x );  // 0 777 0
        foreach( var x in pmat[ 1 ].column ) WriteLine( x );  // 0 0 888 0
    }
}
```

The 3rd code is the use of `class`, which is a reference type. So its array is something like an array of pointers in Fortran (but not an array pointer, as explained in the other answer).

```
using static System.Console;

public class Cell
{
    public double[] column;
}

class Program {

    static void Main() {

        Cell[] pmat;

        pmat = new Cell[ 2 ];  // allocates an array of references (to Cell objects)

        pmat[ 0 ] = new Cell();  // allocates a new object
        pmat[ 1 ] = pmat[ 0 ];   // can point to an existing object

        pmat[ 0 ].column = new double[ 3 ];

        pmat[ 0 ].column[ 1 ] = 777.0;
        pmat[ 1 ].column[ 2 ] = 888.0;  // modifies pmat[0] in practice

        foreach( var x in pmat[ 0 ].column ) WriteLine( x );  // 0 777 888
        foreach( var x in pmat[ 1 ].column ) WriteLine( x );  // 0 777 888
    }
}
```

But the same thing seems possible also with a jagged array (for this particular case):

```
double[][] pmat;
pmat = new double[ 2 ][ ];

pmat[ 0 ] = new double[ 3 ];
pmat[ 1 ] = pmat[ 0 ];

pmat[ 0 ][ 1 ] = 777.0;
pmat[ 1 ][ 2 ] = 888.0;

foreach( var x in pmat[ 0 ] ) WriteLine( x );  // 0 777 888
foreach( var x in pmat[ 1 ] ) WriteLine( x );  // 0 777 888
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any reason, from what has been posted, why those Fortran declarations can't be replaced by your favourite C# approach to defining *jagged arrays*, i.e. an array in which each row has a different number of elements (in this case doubles of course).

First things first, a declaration such as

```
TYPE(Cell), POINTER           :: PMAT(:)
```

does not declare an array of pointers to things of `type(cell)`, it declares a pointer to an array of things of `type(cell)`; i.e. there's one pointer and its pointee is an array.  In Fortran pointers have, approximately, two purposes:

1. They can be used for dynamic allocation of memory during execution; this is almost the same as declaring the variable to be `allocatable`.
2. They can be used to provide multiple references to the same variables, and, in the case of arrays, to refer to different slices of the same array.  You'll know if this is what is going on in your code if you can find variables of the same type with the attribute `target`.  If you can't, then the use of `pointer` is almost certainly just a way of achieving dynamic memory management.

The type definition

```
TYPE Cell
  DOUBLE PRECISION, POINTER :: column(:)
END TYPE Cell
```

declares `cell` to be an array of doubles, how many will be established during execution.  Then along comes

```
TYPE(Cell), POINTER           :: PMAT(:)
```

which declares that `PMAT` will be an array of `cell`s, and bosh, you've got yourself a jagged array of doubles.  This is the common Fortran idiom for declaring jagged arrays. Like all right thinking languages it really regards jagged arrays as an abomination so you have to jump through a hoop to implement them.

I'm not a C# programmer, but I suspect that all those declarations can be implemented in C# along these lines:

```
double[][] pmat = new double[3][];
...
pmat[0] = new double[5];
pmat[1] = new double[4];
pmat[2] = new double[2];
```